# What does COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC stand for?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contacts

```
private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +
            (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +
            " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

What does `COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC` stand for?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Collate is just fancy speak for sort (well sort of). So this is sort ordering based on localized preferences (i.e. current language's alphabet and conventions) in **asc**ending order.

Comment: Do I have to define anything additional to my table schema to be able to use it? Is this SQLite specific or just Android specific? Can I sort by these all my custom columns?

Comment: The ASC means ascending. It need have nothing at all to do with ASCII.

Answer (score 22):

It instructs SQLite to sort non-ASCII characters appropriately. Chars with diacritics (some call them accents) have higher byte codes than the character Z, so a plain ASCII sort wouldn't fit to many foreign languages.

For example, the capital A char's byte code is `0x41` and the capital Z char's is `0x5A`. Then we have the Á (capital A accute) which code in Unicode is `0x00C1`. So a plain byte code sort would result the Á to be after the Z.

But in languages that have this kind of characters the convention is to put those with diacritics as if they didn't have the diacritic. So the Á should be together with the plain A, at least before B.

And to illustrate, we have below a list of names sorted using their bytecode:

- Brenda
- Debby
- George
- Álvaro
- Érico

Now using the `COLLATE LOCALIZED` it would sort by the "base" of the character:

- Álvaro
- Brenda
- Debby
- Érico
- George

Comment: This should be most upvoted, nice explanation with example.

Comment: So COLLATE LOCALIZED will it support if I type A and it display only Álvaro?

Comment: @Start no because COLLATE LOCALIZED is used within the sort expression.

Answer (score 12):

COLLATE is an SQL operator that lets you override the default sort order for strings.  For example, "COLLATE NOCASE" does case-insensitive comparison, and "COLLATE BINARY" does a case-sensitive comparison.

The SQLite C interface lets you define custom collations (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html).